# PHP ADOdb Active Record :: Replace() bug ( or feature? )

Tags: php, mysql, adodb

Here are my code:

```
$user->user_id = 3;
$user->email='';
$user->password=md5('123456');
$user->Replace();
```

then it generate a sql:

```
UPDATE pre_user SET email=,password='e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e' WHERE user_id=3
```

just like what you can see, there is no quote with empty string. then I follow the code to function doquote() at adodb-active-record.inc.php:631 and found the code bellow:

```
    case 'C'://I think this means 'Char' and email field should be this.
    case 'X':
        if (is_null($val)) return 'null';

        if (strlen($val)>0 && 
            (strncmp($val,"'",1) != 0 || substr($val,strlen($val)-1,1) != "'")) { 
            return $db->qstr($val);
            break;
        }
```

it tells if strlen($val)>0...

Why it doesn't add quote to empty string?

Answer (score 0):

`$user->email=''` is not null and has length 0 and `doquote()` is not handling this particular scenario.

You can try:

```
$user->email = NULL;
```

but your database has to allow NULL values for that field.

Comment: why doquote not handle the scenario? In other function like update/save, they all add quote to empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same bug using adodb-active-record.  It is my belief that the **MetaType** lookup function in *adodb-datadict.inc.php* is responsible for classifying your Email column as an 'LVARCHAR' which maps to 'X'.

This is why the doquote code does not catch the length zero string case.

I fixed this in my code base by adding adjusting case 'X' to:

```
 case 'X':
    if (is_null($val)) return 'null';

    if (strlen($val)>0 &&
        (strncmp($val,"'",1) != 0 || substr($val,strlen($val)-1,1) != "'")) {
        return $db->qstr($val);
        break;
    }
    else {
        return 'null';
        break;
    }
```